# Exchange Web Services - Get list of all available "ExtendedProperty"

Tags: exchangewebservices

I have an Exchange Server that contains items with custom fields (*e.g. Contacts and Events with custom ExtendedProperty values*). I am looking for a way to display these fields using Exchange Web Services (EWS).

According to the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633697%28v=exchg.80%29), there's a simple way to retrieve individual `ExtendedProperty` values using the `FindItem` method. Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
     xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
        <t:AdditionalProperties>
          <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c11ff724-aa03-4555-9952-8fa248a11c3e" 
             PropertyName="Expiration Date" PropertyType="String" />
        </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="10" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning" />
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </m:FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, this requires the `PropertySetID` along with the `PropertyType` and `PropertyName`. In my case, I have no idea what `PropertySetIDs` are available, much less the `PropertyType` and `PropertyName`. Is there a way to get a list of all available **Extended Properties**?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to get list of extended (custom) properties. I was using API from Independentsoft and they told me that you have to know (request) which properties want to retrieve with EWS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get the list of Extended Property:
You can use the following code:

`ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
var s = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition ExtendedProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "Expiration Date", MapiPropertyType.String);
var requestedPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ExtendedProp;
var s = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);`

Then iterate through each item in s and then do:

`foreach(var s1 in s)
{
s1.load(requestedPropertySet);
//Here you need to specify the name of each extended property and get it one by one.
}`

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (emails[i].ExtendedProperties.Count > 0)
 {
      Console.WriteLine("Aantal extended properties *" + i + "*" + sAccount + "*" + emails[i].ExtendedProperties.Count + "*");
      foreach (ExtendedProperty extendedProperty in emails[i].ExtendedProperties)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(" Extended Property Name: " + extendedProperty.PropertyDefinition.Name);
          Console.WriteLine(" Extended Property Value: " + extendedProperty.Value);
      }
}
```

Comment: I think you are illustrating how to enumerate through extended properties for a given email. I want to find a list of extended properties for a given mailbox/server without iterating through every single email, contact, calendar appointment, etc.

Comment: Also, can you please explain how you got the list of extended properties in your example? What web method did you call? And what parameters did you use?